# Modifying inputs with RcppArmadillo

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

I am trying to implement LU decomposition with complete pivoting using RcppArmadillo. Luckily I have [this](https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ma221/Matlab/gecp.m) Matlab code that does what I want, but I am having some challenges converting it to Armadillo.

I wanted to make my `gecpLU` function work like `arma::LU` where you input L,U, and P, and the `arma::LU` function modifies the L,U, and P matrices that are inputted rather than returning L, U and P.

I know that with regular `Rcpp` you can modify inputs easily like so:

```
NumericVector example(NumericVector X) {
    X = 2 * X;
    return X;
}
```

This would return a vector two times the input, and also change the input to equal two times its original value. However, I've quickly discovered that this won't work for RcppArmadillo.

```
arma::colvec example(arma::colvec X) {
    X = 2 * X;
    return X;
}
```

I understand this won't change an input when exposed to R, because the `arma` objects are copies of the R objects so you can't directly modify the R object, but I feel like I should still be able to write a function like Armadillo's LU like so:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
int gecpLU(arma::mat L, arma::mat U, arma::mat P, arma::mat Q, arma::mat A) {
  // Take A and overwrite LUPQ such that A=P*L*U*Q
  int n=A.n_rows;
  P.eye(n,n);
  Q.eye(n,n);
  arma::mat AA=A;
  // for (int i=0;i<(n-1);i++) {
  // delete a whole bunch of stuff not relevant to question
  // }
  L.eye(n,n);
  arma::mat tempmat=arma::trimatl(AA);
  tempmat.diag()*=0;
  L=L-tempmat;
  U=arma::trimatu(AA);

  return 0;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List test(arma::mat A) {
  arma::mat L1,U1,P1,L2,U2,P2,Q;
  arma::lu(L1,U1,P1,A);
  gecpLU(L2,U2,P2,Q,A);
  return List::create(_["L1"]=L1,
                      _["U1"]=U1,
                      _["P1"]=P1,
                      _["L2"]=L2,
                      _["U2"]=U2,
                      _["P2"]=P2,
                      _["Q"]=Q);
}
```

In this case, I am not passing R matrices to my `gecpLU` function, but `arma::mat` so it should be able to modify the inputs.

When I run `test` I get matrices for L1, U1, and P1, but 0x0 matrices for L2,U2,P2, and Q. I feel like I must be misunderstanding something. Is it possible to modify inputs with RcppArmadillo? If not what is the best way to output 4 matrices? A list?

Comment: The simplest way is to transfer in Rcpp vectors, and create `arma` objects using the auxiliary constructors (see the `Advanced constructors` sections in http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Col for more information).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under:

```
int gecpLU(arma::mat L, arma::mat U, arma::mat P, arma::mat Q, arma::mat A)
```

You are creating new copies of each of those matrices and then at the end of the function they are destroyed.

What you are expecting is the object gets modified. To do that, you need to append at the end of the object type a `&` so that the compiler knows to obtain the reference of the object.

```
void gecpLU(arma::mat& L, arma::mat& U, arma::mat& P, arma::mat& Q, arma::mat& A)
```

Note, I also changed the return type of `gecpLU` from `int` to `void`. See:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
void gecpLU(arma::mat& L, arma::mat& U, arma::mat& P, arma::mat& Q, arma::mat& A) {
  // Take A and overwrite LUPQ such that A=P*L*U*Q
  int n=A.n_rows;
  P.eye(n,n);
  Q.eye(n,n);
  arma::mat AA=A;
  // for (int i=0;i<(n-1);i++) {
  // delete a whole bunch of stuff not relevant to question
  // }
  L.eye(n,n);
  arma::mat tempmat=arma::trimatl(AA);
  tempmat.diag()*=0;
  L=L-tempmat;
  U=arma::trimatu(AA);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List test(arma::mat A) {
  arma::mat L1,U1,P1,L2,U2,P2,Q;
  arma::lu(L1,U1,P1,A);
  gecpLU(L2,U2,P2,Q,A);
  return List::create(_["L1"]=L1,
                      _["U1"]=U1,
                      _["P1"]=P1,
                      _["L2"]=L2,
                      _["U2"]=U2,
                      _["P2"]=P2,
                      _["Q"]=Q);
}
```

Simple makeshift example to demonstrate the pass by reference (that enables modification) vs. pass by copy (that destroys the object at the end)

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;

void reference_obj(arma::vec& y){
  y.fill(1);
}

void copy_obj(arma::vec y){
  y.fill(0);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec on_reference_mod(arma::vec x) {

  reference_obj(x);

  return x;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec on_copy_mod(arma::vec x) {

  copy_obj(x);

  return x;
}

/*** R
# Should get a vector of 1's
on_reference_mod(1:10)

# Should get a vector of 1:10
on_copy_mod(1:10)
*/
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was missing something.