Tbb based row sum of an armadillo matrix
Following the tbb example for parallel_reduce here with a basic datatypes, I wanted to try and implement a tbb version of a row sum of an Armadillo matrix. (I realize the use of arma::sum for this purpose, but this was an attempt at getting to know tbb, Armadillo and how they work together a bit better. )
The following code was aimed to loop over columns of a matrix X, and add the column values to a running total vector. It compiles fine but crashes at run time. I am wondering where I am going wrong. Is the X.col(j) use is incorrect? Thank you!
arma::vec parallelRowsumTBB_withArma(arma::mat X){

   arma::vec y=tbb::parallel_reduce(
      tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(0,X.n_cols),
      arma::vec(X.n_rows).fill(0),
      [&](const tbb::blocked_range<size_t>& r, arma::vec runningTotal) { 
         for(int j=r.begin(); j!=r.end(); ++j){
            runningTotal = runningTotal + X.col(j);
         }
         return runningTotal;
      },
      [](arma::vec a, arma::vec b){
         return a + b;
      }
   );
   return y;
}


A related question/answer seems to be here: https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/parallel-aggregate-to-vector/

That is a 'frequently asked question': you cannot have any parallel code have any callback or interaction with the main R process which is not safe for such callback.  And Armadillo data structures provided by RcppArmadillo reuse (by default) the R memory so you can potentially have interactions with R's processs via the gc().
See the RcppParallel package (with relies on TBB) and its documentation for an alternative: RMatrix and RVector.  Or ensure your RcppArmadillo objects are in fact distinct copies.

Thanks @Ada Lovelace. Aren't we creating a copy of the R matrix for the function by using arma::mat without an adjacent & in the argument ? (An example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36558738/modifying-inputs-with-rcpparmadillo . The same thread also make it appear that passing by reference is no problem as well. I think I am quite confused.  )

No, see the documentation for Armadillo matrices and vectors, section 'advanced constructors, note the argument for copy_aux_mem and then peruse the RcppArmadillo code: copy_aux_mem is set to false for an efficiency gain.  And precisely the sort of problem my answer describes.

Thanks @Ada Lovelace. I will follow up on the copy_aux_mem after implementation. In the context of our discussion, could you describe then why the in place change of an R matrix in this thread works? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36558738/modifying-inputs-with-rcpparmadillo . I guess I am struggling to see the difference between  the approach taken by the one in the link, and the one we posted above. Thank you very much.

Please take a close look at the vignette of package RcppParallel which covers this.  R is a single-threaded program with its internal memory management.  You can spawn parallel computations, R itself does so in a few places when OpenMP is available but you have to be very diligent and 'not call back'.  As I explained. your first approach here violated that.  If you search StackOverflow carefully you will see that issue discussed a few times over the years.  It is a common mistake, an understandable one ... but still a mistake.  Good luck.

Thank you @Ada Lovelace. I will look at the vignette.

My pleasure.  If you wouldn't mind, please consider upvoting / accepting the answer.  I gave you the core answer above even if it took a bit of Q & A for it to settle.
